# Multiline if Statements

Tags: apex

Is it possible to have an if statement on multiple lines? I currently have an apex class with a large conditional statement and I would like to have it on multiple lines to improve readability.

Answer (score 7):

Yes! The example below works just fine

```
string a;
string b;
string c;

if (a == b || 
    b == c) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go by

**Creating small meaningful functions**

Answering the original question, Yes the conditions in apex can be put on multiple lines.

As the main purpose to splitting conditions on multiple lines is code readability,
Going further I would suggest to *create small meaningful functions, This will make your code even more readable.*

Once I had developed a functionality to take backup of data, here is snippet of that code.

This is more readable than any kind of indentation.

```
 private Boolean isEligibleForBackup(String interval, Date lastBackupDate) {
        return (isEligibleForDailyBackup(interval, lastBackupDate)
                || isEligibleForWeeklyBackup(interval, lastBackupDate)
                || isEligibleForMonthlyBackup(interval, lastBackupDate));
    }

    private Boolean isEligibleForDailyBackup(String interval, Date lastBackupDate) {
        return (interval.equalsIgnoreCase('daily')
                && lastBackupDate.daysBetween(System.today()) >= 1);
    }

    private Boolean isEligibleForWeeklyBackup(String interval, Date lastBackupDate) {
        return (interval.equalsIgnoreCase('weekly')
                && lastBackupDate.daysBetween(System.today()) >= 7);
    }

    private Boolean isEligibleForMonthlyBackup(String interval, Date lastBackupDate) {
        return (interval.equalsIgnoreCase('monthly')
                && monthsBetween(lastBackupDate, System.today()) > 0);
    }
```